# Reverse order of XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm using PHP to output data from an XML file. It's defaulting to chronological order, which I'd like to reverse. Is this possible with PHP? If so, how?

Here's my [page](http://bit.ly/j2n0m4) and code:

```
    $file = 'http://www.gostanford.com/data/xml/events/m-baskbl/2010/index.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

        foreach ($xml as $event_date) {
        if(!empty($event_date->event['vn']) && !empty($event_date->event['hn']) && !empty($event_date->event['vs']) && !empty($event_date->event['hs']))
        { 
            echo '<li>';
                echo '<h3>', $event_date->event['vn'], ' vs ', $event_date->event['hn'], '</h3>';
                echo '<p><strong>', $event_date->event['vs'], ' - ', $event_date->event['hs'], '</strong></p>';
                echo '<p>', date('F j, Y', strtotime($event_date['date'])), '</p>';
            echo '</li>';   
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the first answer notes, this may not be a good idea on big XML documents. The simplest and most portable code for PHP 5.1.2 and above may be to use SimpleXML. It may have been built in to earlier PHP versions, but it is standard after 5.1.2.

```
<?php

$file = 'http://www.gostanford.com/data/xml/events/m-baskbl/2010/index.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

if ($xml === false) {
  echo "Couldn't load file\n";
  exit (1);
}

$xmlArray = array();

foreach ($xml as $event_date) $xmlArray[] = $event_date;

$xmlArray = array_reverse($xmlArray);

foreach ($xmlArray as $event_date) {
    if(!empty($event_date->event['vn']) && !empty($event_date->event['hn']) && !empty($event_date->event['vs']) && !empty($event_date->event['hs']))
    {
            echo '<li>';
                echo '<h3>', $event_date->event['vn'], ' vs ', $event_date->event['hn'], '</h3>';
                echo '<p><strong>', $event_date->event['vs'], ' - ', $event_date->event['hs'], '</strong></p>';
                echo '<p>', $event_date['date'], '</p>';
                echo '<p>', $event_date->event['local_time'], '</p>';
            echo '</li>';
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: @Erik Nedwidek - thanks and yes, I'm using *simplexml_load_file* with an external XML file and updated my question to show that. I can't seem to get your code to work - do I need to change *simplexml_load_file* to use *simplexmlelement* instead?

Comment: @Ryan - You shouldn't need to do anything to simplexml_load_file. If it successfully loads the xml file, it returns a SimpleXMLElement object (false on failure). In the second foreach the $xml needs to be $xmlArray. (fixed the orignal answer)

Comment: @Erik Nedwidek When I try your updated answer I get this: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan - Not a clue. I'm using PHP 5.3.6 on Fedora 14.Output of "php -v": PHP 5.3.6 (cli) (built: Mar 17 2011 20:58:15)

Comment: @Erik Nedwidek Can you edit your answer and add the simplexml_load_file? The XML file URL is in my edited answer. Thank you.

Comment: That's the exact script that I'm using. It's not on a server, I'm just running it as "php test.php" on the command line.

Comment: @Erik Nedwidek weird - been refreshing this page but it just *now* showed me your edited answer. It works perfectly! Thank you for the concise and effective code :)

Answer (score 2):

If `$xml` is just an array, you can use `array_reverse($xml)` to reverse it:

```
foreach (array_reverse($xml) as $event_date) {
  // etc
}
```

But, if it's long, that might not be efficient. You could use a manual for-loop with decrementing indices:

```
for ($i = sizeof($xml) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
  // use $xml[$i] to access each element
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that generates this error: Warning: array_reverse() [function.array-reverse]: The argument should be an array on line 14

Comment: The xml object is not really an array. It implements Traversable so it can be used in foreach, but not treated as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you can read your xml to an array and print in reverse order. However, this might not be a good idea for a long list.

**EDIT:**

```
foreach($xml as $event_date){
    if(!empty($event_date->event['vn']) && !empty($event_date->event['hn']) && !empty($event_date->event['vs']) && !empty($event_date->event['hs']))
    { 
        $my[]=array (
             "vn" => $event_date->event['vn'],
             "hn" => $event_date->event['hn']
             ...
        );
    }
}

for($i=count($my)-1;$i>=0;$i--) {
    echo '<li>';
        echo '<h3>', $my[$i]['vn'], ' vs ', $my[$i]['hn'];
        ...
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Hope this helps, it might need fixes.

Comment: How can I do that? The list isn't that long - maybe 200-300 lines max.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. I need it to appear in reverse chronological order. Do you know how to get that working?

Comment: sorry for late response, you can sort the array in between, as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Can you reverse your output instead of the xml? IE:

```
  $arr = array();
  foreach($xml as $event_date){
        if(!empty($event_date->event['vn']) && !empty($event_date->event['hn']) && !empty($event_date->event['vs']) && !empty($event_date->event['hs']))
        { 
        $strLine = "";
        $strLine .= '<li>';
        $strLine .= '<h3>'. $event_date->event['vn']. ' vs '. $event_date->event['hn']. '</h3>';
        $strLine .= '<p><strong>'. $event_date->event['vs']. ' - '. $event_date->event['hs']. '</strong></p>';
        $strLine .= '<p>'. $event_date['date']. '</p>';
        $strLine .= '<p>'. $event_date->event['local_time']. '</p>';
        $strLine .= '</li>';   
        $arr[] = $strLine;
        }
    }
    $arr = array_reverse($arr);
    foreach ($arr as $line)
    {
        echo $line;
    }
```

Comment: thanks but there are several syntax errors in your example that I'm not sure how to correct. Can you edit your code?

Comment: @Ryan Sorry. Still in javascript mode with the "var." Other than that everything checks out on my IDE. Is there a specific error you are getting?

Comment: In Dreamweaver the four strLine inside the li are marked incorrect. When I upload your code I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' on line 19

Comment: @Ryan, ok that should be fixed.